Do all Lie groups possess finite dimensional representations?
When talking about Lie groups one usually gets to see matrix Lie group examples like $U(n), O(n), Gl_n(\mathbb K), Sl_n(\mathbb K),\dots$ So the question "Are there any non matrix Lie groups?" definitely needs to be asked. Well, there are some.
An imaginable way to proof this (if we would not know that it's false), would be to find, for a given Lie group $G$, some finite dimensional, faithful representations. But the question if $G$ even has any representations has no obvious answer, at least, not from my point of view.
When considering finite groups, it is easy to find a faithful, finite dimensional representation, namely the group ring/-algebra. So I was trying to adapt this strategy to an arbitrary Lie group $G$:
take a Haar measure, get $L^1(G)$ the integrable functions with respect to that measure and the regular representation: $L:G \to \text{Aut}( L^1(G)), s \mapsto L_s$ , while $L_s$ maps $f$ on the function $x\mapsto f(s^{-1}x)$. I did not check every detail, but I am very confident to be able to proof that this is a faithful representation. But the thing is: it's most likely not finite dimensional.
So the question remains: does $G$ have a  finite dimensional (non-trivial) representation $(V, \rho)?$
I could imagine that if so one could construct a faithful, finite dimensional representation out of it what would be a contradiction, but I am far beyond proving this.
So if anyone knows a Lie group without finite dimensional representations, or a proof that $G$ must have a non-trivial finite dimensional representation, please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Do you at least assume that your group is connected? Otherwise, trivial representation is all what you will get in general. Do you know what the adjoint representation is?

@MoisheKohan No i mean for arbitrary lie groups. I have heard about the adjoint representation and know basically what it is. I assume that its not continuous in general, from what you say. Well anyways feel free to give me information about the connected case, if you have any.

If you are interested in Lie groups you should consider reading a textbook. Adjoint representation for study of Lie groups is like derivative to calculus.

If you are asking about arbitrary Lie groups, then there are many examples of discrete groups which have only trivial matrix representation, even finitely generated ones, for instance Higman groups.
If you restrict to Lie groups with finitely many connected components, then they all admit nontrivial matrix representations. Unless the identity component is a central subgroup, you can use the adjoint representation. The remaining case I am leaving to you to work out (start by analyzing the case of connected abelian Lie groups).

Thank you! For some reason this motivates me more than a detailed solution!
